# Insert richtext or html in word online using office app

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am trying to insert HTML text in a content control using an Office App from Word Online. Unfortunately, it is not working for me. The same code works if I run it on the desktop version of Word.

For Word Online somehow I can insert only plain text and nothing else. Can anyone please help me with this?
This is the complete Word.Run method:

```
 Word.run(function(context) {
        var htmlText = ' <h1>Test HTML Text</h1>'

        var range = context.document.getSelection();

        var myContentControl = range.insertContentControl();
        myContentControl.tag = 'Testtag';
        myContentControl.title = 'TestTitle';

        myContentControl.insertHtml(htmlText, 'end');

        myContentControl.cannotEdit = false;
        myContentControl.cannotDelete = false;

        context.load(myContentControl, 'id');

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
        // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            console.log('Created content control with id: ' + myContentControl.id);
        });
    })
```

Can anyone please help me with what am I missing to achieve the same in word online.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. You're missing some details that make it hard to know whats going on. Could you provide a more complete code sample and any errors your seeing in the console?

Comment: Please provide the complete Word.run method. Trying to reproduce your issue is much easier when you do that. Thanks.

Comment: I tried and am able to insert html on word online, it is working correctly. So please provide the detailed exception code you got and it would be good if you can provide your issue document.

Comment: @MSFT-Jipyua  can please share your sample code with me?

Comment: @RickKirkham I have updated the question with the compete  rum method.

Comment: I am using your code actually. Also what do you mean " insert only plain text and nothing else"? what else do you expect? you mean you expect a Header1 format? Rich client also didn't have a format.

Comment: Yes I intend to insert rich text in the content control. So as I said again if I use html code with <h1> tag and  run the code on the desktop word I get the expected results, but if i run the same code for Word online I don't get the text rich text, infact the code does not do anything except adding the content control.
So my requirement is to insert rich text in the word online and not in desktop word application.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on word online. on word online I can successfully insert the content control and the text "Test HTML Text". And they are with the same formatting as on word desktop. So it would be good if you can provide a video and the document that how you repro this issue.

Comment: @MSFT-Jipyua can you please help me with how you did it? if you can also help me with the steps on how you deployed the add-in to word online, may be I am missing something.